# Soft-Scroll jacking in React

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, frontend

I need help implementing an interaction like the one on https://www.apple.com/mac-mini/, where there is one constant navigation slider, and as the user scrolls down the text around it shifts. This is my current progress - http://mukit.io/scroll-test.

This is just a demo, the actual site is in React and I'm having trouble with JQuery/React as well as making the experience as seamless as they did here. Currently, I'm playing with changing the z-axis, but the results aren't great.

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: @AlexW I don't know what the best strategy is to implement such behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the active item based on target div Y position vs height of scrolled document.
This can be done in a way similar to:

```
import React from 'react';

let lastScrollY = 0;
let ticking = false;

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  nav = React.createRef();

  handleScroll = () => {
    lastScrollY = window.scrollY;

    if (!ticking) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.nav.current.style.top = `${lastScrollY}px`;
        ticking = false;
      });

      ticking = true;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav ref={this.nav}>
        </nav>
      <div>
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can try https://github.com/makotot/react-scrollspy which do exactly what are you looking for.